# What is the role of towers in Romanesque architecture?

Tags: religion, christianity, architecture

I'm currently reading some books about romanesque architecture. I would like to know the roles of towers that many religious buildings have. I have some guesses, so I would like you to tell me if these guesses are true or wrong.

First example : St. Pierre Cathedrale (Treves)
[image]

We can see small rounded towers. My guess, everytime, that kind of tower is used for stairs, eventually to defend the building at some point.

The squared towers, my guess, are present as a symbol of the gate of the celestial Jerusalem, but for what else are they used ? My personal experience pushes me to say: for bells, but bells don't occupy the whole tower.

Also, I'm curious if the ground section of a tower is linked to its height.

Another example : St. Michel (Hildesheim)
[image]

As we can see, there are only crossing towers and small rounded towers. I guess, the squared towers are used for bells too.

*the part in italics contains mistake, see the comments*

*To finish, it seems (maybe I'm wrong on that point) that temples used before Christianity, Romans/Greeks (pagan) had twin towers (like the one we can see on the picture of St. Pierre). So I would like to know if the celestial representation of Jerusalem has its origin in Roman/Greek temples (pagan).*

Comment: wikipedia [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanesque_architecture#Church_towers) the arrangement of towers varies by region and country. That would seem to undercut the hypothesis.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace what I read at your link is already in my books. I want more precision. Anyway thank you

Comment: not just that, but the assumption that pre-Christian temples had towers at all is wrong. See the Parthenon, see the Roman Pantheon, see many many others. Most had no towers at all.

Comment: I think it would be impossible to define it in simple rules, as they mentioned it depends on the country, which movement was influenced, if they had enough material to build an entire new tower or next to the apse,...Two examples here in Spain: An abbot in Catalonia went to Italy to see how churches were build there and was influenced by the lombardic architecture, but if you go to Segovia there is a church that was used by templars and its said that was based in the Church of the Holy Sepulchre of Jerusalem. The church of Segovia (Veracruz) was the guideline for others as well.

Comment: @jwenting your guess sound right. I re-read the part of the book where I thought have read my assumption. It's not about pagan temple but "early Christian" in Roman era.

Comment: @AlexBcn actually in one book I have, the front faces of churchs are classed by their number of towers, but they don't explain the role of the towers. I can understand that each church can have some specificity, but it should be possible to class the role of tower just by doing statistics. Maybe nobody did it yet...

Comment: @bob-Looterofelvishrealms that would be highly error prone, as many churches have had towers added or removed over time, others have had towers start construction but never completed (often because the donors ran out of money halfway through construction), etc. etc.

Comment: @jwenting, remember, I talk about the romanesque era. Means, only the churches built during this era and how they looked when they were fully built. For example, I know that the cathedral of Strasbourg today doesn't look the same as circa 1000 AD. Even if a church is modified during the romanesque era, I guess (it's my personal guess) the modification stayed close of the usual romanesque architecture of that time. Anyway, I think the best would like to class churches how they looked when they were "sacred" (don't sure about the word, english isn't my mother tongue).

Comment: Sanctified? Just a guess at the right word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say, "My personal experience push me to say : for bells, but bells don't occupy the whole tower."

They do not have to occupy the whole tower, but for maximum effect, they have to be hung quite high - which means that you need the rest of the tower to give height to the bell chamber and - at least in the English tradition - to give enough space for efficient work on a bellrope.

So the question might be - "What other uses did people make of the towers which they needed for bells?"

Seriously, however, I suspect the most important factor is an artistic/cultural one. Most churches from the Romanesque period onward were designed not just to be a place for communal worship. They were statements about the wealth and power of the community which built them, or the local magnate who paid for them or even about the beauty which could be produced by the work and dedication of the builders (e.g. at Chartres).

The model for ostentation was the defensive structure of the castle or the great house. These usually had towers for military reasons, but that establishes towers as a part of the "building to impress" vocabulary. As you have pointed out impressive gates at the entrance to a city are not new - cities have been guarding their entrances with fortified structures with good vantage points for almost as long as there have been cities.

So what more natural, when you want "look at me" architecture, than a building which rises high above its surroundings and can be seen from miles away? It's worth it - when thinking about medieval architecture - to imagine any town and most cities as places where nearly all the available buildings were no more than 1 or 2 stories high and built of wood. Towers of stone, reaching up to God's Heaven were a powerful statement and a psychologically unsubtle reminder of the importance of that building and those who controlled it.

Comment: your post make sense let me some time to reread and think about it.

Comment: I was thinking today about the bastides occupied by the cathars. I heard that the towers of churchs were used to keep an eye on the surroundings.Your answer seems good enough to me to be accepted. Thank you (2 years after the initial post).

Answer (score 0):

I read on wiki some old monasteries and cathedrals include [conjuratories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjuratory) in their towers, small religious buildings from which ceremonies were conducted to bless the fields and ward off calamities caused by the weather.  People believed in weather spells during the romanesque period.

Comment: There are still conjuratories in some churches in Catalonia, but they aren't tower churches but separate small buildings, and they aren't high. https://ca.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categoria:Comunidors

Answer (score -3):

Romanesque architecture
It is an early architectural style characterised by thick walls and narrow windows.

[Mozaweb Videos](http://www.mozaweb.com/Extra-Videos-Romanesque_architecture-210251)

Comment: I don't see how this addresses the actual question.

Comment: I feel kind of leaning towards calling this a link-only answer.